# Why I get "Fatal error: in ...smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 8" error message?

Tags: comments, smarty, fatal-error, diacritics

I am migrating an old project from PHP 5.X to 7.0.4 and Smarty from 2.6.27 to 3.1.29. After solving several smaller issues, I got a surprising error message

> Fatal error: in C:...\smarty-3.1.29\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 8

The strange thing is that the 8th line of this file is the middle of a multi-line phpdoc comment. There is no code execution at all.

Why is this error message displayed and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a painful investigation, it turned out that the line number of the error message is OK but the file name is not. The error was not in the 8th line of the mentioned php code. It was in the 8th line of my template instead.

The template file was an ISO-8859-2 encoded file with some international characters:

```
BLAH
{ * részletezés  * }
BLA
```

The word "részletezés" in the 8th line of the template file contained the culprit characters in it.

Older smarty version (2.X) was running fine with international smarty comments. The problem was that the error message was misleading.

After changing the international characters to its English counterparts, the error disappeared.